# php formatting dates for mysql

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert php date to mysql format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format)

I have a date field which lets users type in their birthday in `m/d/Y` format (for example `06/01/1982`) but just in case I also made my validation accept month and day values without any leading 0 (`6/1/1982`).

How can I convert these dates to `Y-m-d` for use in MySQL?

Other valid dates are `6/01/1982` and `06/1/1982`.

Comment: Why do you hate date fields ? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+convert+date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use date() and strtotime() together like such:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('06/01/1982'));
```

That will give you

```
1982-06-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I would validate all input using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (which will handle all major date formats).

On the insert, cast it to the proper format using the inverse: [`strftime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

```
$userValidatedDate = strtotime($_GET['date']);
//...
$sqlDate = strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$userValidatedDate);
```