# PHP: Convert "13 September 2013 - 23:55" to SQL Server formatted datetime format

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Trying to get my head around this, but can't seem to figure it out. I'm using PHP and attempting to convert the user-submitted date/time selection which outputs:

```
13 September 2013 - 23:55
```

I would like to convert that to the standard SQL Server format like:

```
2013-09-13 23:55:00.000
```

I've messed with the PHP strtotime() function sending it only the "13 September 2013" part, but it only outputs a long (seemingly) random number.

Is there any easier method for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert php date to mysql format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format)

Answer (score 2):

Have a go with:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i','13 September 2013 - 23:55');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This lets you specify a format to read from.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` returns the unix timestamp, you need to turn it to date string.

```
php > echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('13 September 2013 23:55'));
2013-09-13 23:55:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two separate functions,

1. for converting month to numeric
2. year to two digit number

and after that you can break the user input to its desired three parts.