# How to compare php variable to date column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

```
SELECT H.house_code, H.description
FROM House H
INNER JOIN Room_Book RB
ON H.house_code=RB.house_code
WHERE RB.checkin < '2014-02-20'
```

OR

```
SELECT H.house_code, H.description
FROM House H
INNER JOIN Room_Book RB
ON H.house_code=RB.house_code
WHERE RB.checkin < '$inputdate'
```

Hi, I am trying to compare a value from PHP variable to date column in MySQL.

The format for both are `yyyy-mm-dd`, however, it doesnt seem to work correctly.

Is there anything that I am missing in format of those date values?

Comment: When posting code, use the `{}` button to properly format it in the editor.

Comment: You might consider converting [the php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format) so you can guarantee the format.

Comment: also make sure the data attribute in MySQL is of `DATE` type

Comment: what you've shown should work, so you have an error in something you did not tell, or something isn't in the way you tell it.

Comment: Solved,  Thank you for your comments.    I changed the format of php variable to be date and set correct alias on fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RB.checkin < STR_TO_DATE('$inputdate','%d,%m,%Y')
```

Have Mysql perform the conversion to remove any of the guesswork.