# updating fields in mysql table using values from a drop down menu

Tags: php

I am currently having problems with editing fields from a  mysql database table using values from a drop-down list. The fields i want to be able to modify and update on mysql database are Type and time which are selected from a drop-down list in my webpage. Whenever i change the 'type' from down menu, it is able to update the database, but has an affect on the 'time' field in the database updates the value to 00:00:00.

This is main part of my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

$type =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['testtype']);


  $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['timeslot']);

     $query = "UPDATE bookings1 SET Type = '$type', Timeslot = '$time' WHERE booking_id = '$id'";

     $sqlquery = $mysqli->query($query);

}

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM bookings1 WHERE booking_id = '$id'";

$results = $mysqli->query($sqlquery);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {

 while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

       echo '<form method = "post"  action = "">';

          echo'Type:  <select id =  name ="testtype" > 

           <option value =""> '. $row["Type"].'  </option>

        <option value = "classIV"  > Class IV - Cars,light-vans,Motorcaravans (£35.00) </option>
        <option value = "classV" > Class V - Private Passenger vehicles & Minibuses (£44.99) </option>
        <option value = "classVI" > Class VI - Goods vehicles (£54.99) </option>
        <option value = "TaxiMOT" > Taxi MOT - Taxi vehicles (£35.00) </option>
        </select></br></br>';

      echo'Time:  <select id = "timeslot"  name ="timeslot" > 

        <option value =""> '. $row["Timeslot"].'  </option>

        <option value = "08:30" > 08:30 </option>

        <option value = "09:15" > 09:15 </option>

        <option value = "10:00" > 10:00 </option>

        <option value = "10:45" > 10:45 </option>

        <option value = "11:30" > 11:30 </option>

        <option value = "12:15" > 12:15 </option>

        <option value = "13:00" > 13:00 </option>

        <option value = "13:45" > 13:45 </option>

        <option value = "14:30" > 14:30 </option>

        <option value = "15:15" > 15:15 </option>

        <option value = "16:00" > 16:00 </option>

        <option value = "16:45" > 16:45 </option>

        <option value = "17:30" > 17:30 </option> 

        </select>

       echo '<input type = "submit" = name = "update" value = "update" />';

        echo '</form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the date/time field according to the database column you're putting it in:

1. If your MySQL column is DATE type:

   $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
2. If your MySQL column is DATETIME type:

   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));

[convert php date to mysql format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format)

Comment: I have updated my question, its not having affect on the date, only affects the time. Whenever i select an option on the 'type' drop-down list, this affects the time field and displays it as 00:00:00