# Convert a datetime format to match MySQL's datetime with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need a way to convert this format `Tue, 20 Oct 2015 17:43:23 0000`
to the datetime format that `MySQL` accepts.

I have tried to convert it with `strtotime()` but the function returns a negative number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert php date to mysql format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be the trailing zeroes, by trimming them from the date string it seems to work fine. The code below uses one of the `Date` constants - change that for the format desired.

```
$d='Tue, 20 Oct 2015 17:43:23 0000';
echo date( DATE_COOKIE, strtotime( trim($d,' 0000') ) );
outputs -> Tuesday, 20-Oct-15 17:43:23 BST

echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( trim($d,' 0000') ) );
outputs -> 2015-10-20 17:43:23
```

Comment: As @Sergio pointed out, that would appear to be the timezone - if it is always simply zeroes then the above should be fine, however, if it changes to say `0100` or whatever then the trim function might need to be replaced with some sort of regex..

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your time specified as the `$inputtime` variable:

`strftime("%F %H:%M:%S", strtotime($inputtime))`

Comment: But in that case it doesn't pay attention to time zone, but it should

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your time format `Tue, 20 Oct 2015 17:43:23 0000`. Here `0000` means time zone. But it should have format `+` or `-` before value to work properly.  Look at example:

`echo strtotime("Tue, 20 Oct 2015 17:43:23 +0000");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('r',your date);
$date = $date->format(format that you need);
```