# php convert date to mysql format

Tags: php, mysql

I have gone through [convert php date to mysql format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format) but still I have few issues and questions,

In general, my application, can input dates in `Y-m-d`, `d-m-y`, `m-d-Y`, `jS`, `F Y` format, or even with `'/'` separator.

I want this dates to be converted in to `MYSQL Y-m-d` format,
I tried as below, but it shows different output than expected,

Non working

```
date_format(date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', '02-25-2016'), 'Y-m-d');
```

Working

```
date_format(date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', '25-02-2016'), 'Y-m-d');
```

So it seems format and string to be match in same way, otherwise its not interpreting correctly,

What is best way to convert above 4 format inputs to mysql(Y-m-d) format?

Thanks advanced,

Comment: Why on earth do you expect `date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', '02-25-2016')` to work? How many years have 25 months? Of course the date value and the format mask have to match..... that's the whole point of `date_create_from_format()`!!!

Comment: @MarkBaker, i know that won't work, that's reason i asked what way to get it work regardless of input date format :-)

Comment: Have you tried using $date = new \DateTime($date_str); echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: Can you add your output please.

Comment: You'll need to write the code, which determines the input format. That's the only solution.

Comment: There cannot be one all singing all dancing date format convertor, because of dates like `01-02-2016`.... is that 1st February, or 2nd January? PHP will make a decision for you based on `/` or `-` separator, but there's no guarantee that it will be correct..... you need to control the date formats that you use so that you can eliminate ambiguities.... the whole point of the `date_create_from_format()` function is for you to tell PHP what format the date is, so that is parser can make the right decision

Comment: I think you need to wait for the new compiler, they are calling it _Think it and it shall be coded_ They are nearly ready to release, they just need to collect some more __pixie dust__ to make it work

Comment: @rjcode i think there is no way your code can determine the format, because the date 25-02-2016 can be converted, but what will you do if user selects 02-02-2016 date?

Comment: Make sure that when you pass a date to the script you also pass along the date format to avoid ambiguity, like Mark pointed out

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Carbon for any date processing in PHP these days.

Creating date by parsing strings is simple enough...
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

Getting the output in a format you need is also simple...
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use this function: [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Using this, you need to create a date by specifying the particular format.

Try this:

```
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-05-26');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
 echo "<hr/>";

 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '26-05-2016');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
 echo "<hr/>";

 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '05-26-2016');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
 echo "<hr/>";

 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('jS F Y', '26th May 2016');
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all suggestions, i think i found my logic,
My date format selection is stored in sql db, so will try as below,

```
date_format(date_create_from_format('format from db', 'user entered format'), 'Y-m-d');
```

As **user entered format** is stored in db, so i will pull that in this date_format function, so both will match and i can convert to Y-m-d!

Thanks,