# MYSQL Date select between

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using an API to collect some data from my client. however the date's of orders come in this format 06/09/2016 07:30PM UTC

at the moment I am just putting the data into my MYSQL table and storing it as Varchar,all fine for now but I will want to run some queries using select between (the range of dates)

I have tried changing the table structure so the column is Date instead of varchar but the dates come in as all 00000000's

I can return records using wild cards but not in a between range of dates.

Im thinking of trimming the data I don't need from the end then putting into a new table

Any suggestions on the best way to proceed would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a virtual persistent Column like this. so you can store your date as string and MySQL direct convert it to DATETIME. So you can use the new field for BETWEEN and you can also create a INDEX on the new field

```
CREATE TABLE `dd` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `utc` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nd` DATETIME AS (STR_TO_DATE(utc, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i%p') ) persistent,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB []> CREATE TABLE `dd` (
    ->   `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `utc` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `nd` DATETIME AS (STR_TO_DATE(utc, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i%p') ) persistent,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

MariaDB []> INSERT INTO `dd` (`utc`)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('06/09/2016 07:30PM UTC');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.13 sec)

MariaDB []> select * from dd;
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
| id | utc                    | nd                  |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 06/09/2016 07:30PM UTC | 2016-09-06 19:30:00 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Comment: Again thank you, I will convert all old data using the examples answered above, but I will change the table I pull the data into using your suggestion, that way I wont have to change anything else in the future after convert the old data. thanks again.

Comment: getting this error when trying to run your sample table code  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (STR_TO_DATE(utc, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i%p') ) persistent, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ' at line 4 all looks good to me but I have been looking at queries for hours, did it run on your machine ?

Comment: is it possible that not have a old MySQL / MariaDB Version. please post the result of: SELECT VERSION();

Comment: select str_to_date(date_column, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i%p')
from your_table

Comment: it not str_to_date, its the virtual persistent field where automatic calculate the field

Comment: just looked an yes you are correct not a feature in my version. its my hosted server so no chance of changing. any work arounds you can think of, that solution was nice and clean

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
select str_to_date(date_column, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i%p')
from your_table
```

to convert it to date: [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/63475).

You could add another column of type `datetime` and put the values there.

```
update your_table
set new_date_column = str_to_date(old_date_column, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i%p')
```

Then drop the old column and rename the new one.

see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for how to format date strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed the %p in the Mysql manuals datetime table.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that I would strongly suggest.

### Change the field to a DateTime

The reasoning behind this is that MySQL does a lot of optimizations when doing Date-math. Fortunately, you can still insert/update the field in the format of YYYY-MM-DD. However to get by your problem of converting VARCHAR into a valid DATETIME, I would do the following steps:

1. Create a **new field** calling it something else.
2. Do an UPDATE of your table, and save all of the old values into the new column. Ex:

`UPDATE myTable SET newField = STR_TO_DATE(oldField, "%d/%m/%Y %h:%i%p");`

3. Drop the old column and rename the new one to the old name.

Like I said, MySQL does a lot of different optimizations to help with Date-math. This also allows you to do the second part of this...

### BETWEEN is your friend

Using the keyword BETWEEN saves a lot of time, and it is also heavily optimized. So you can do the following very easily:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate BETWEEN "2016-01-01" AND "2016-05-05";`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. between is what I was trying to use before I saw the data was stored as varchar and not date, I was trying to use wild cards and between together (obviously not working). I will convert all old data to a new column for easier select queries.