# Change date string into mysql date field

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

I have a date in input type text with format like ( 23-12-2017)
I want using php to change it into mysql date format 
Thx in advance

Comment: Did you read of this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to find what you should use? Also, do you have any code examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Or just this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790930/convert-php-date-to-mysql-format